# lagrange interpolation question here

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

We have the function : 
$f(x)=\cos(x) + \sin(x)$ and $x_0=0, 
x_1=0.25  , x_2=0.5, x_3=1$

a)Find Lagrange polynomial for this function.

c)Find  the real approximation error.

d)Find the limit of the maximum error in $[x_0, x_3]$

Dont ask me why there isnt b).Theres no b) in my book.
I have solved a and d .Please check them out.Thing is I dont know how to solve c)
Here are my solutions.

[image: First image]
[image: Second image]
[image: Third image]

EDIT : THeres a problem in my lagrange polynom but I dont know what...because my solution is different to this 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0.25%2C+1.2163%7D%2C%7B0.5%2C+1.357%7D%2C%7B1%2C+1.3817%7D

Comment: The polynomial you get can't be right because $p(x_0)\neq f(x_0)$.

Comment: But I have checked them many times..anyway please what do you think about d)?

Comment: Your $f(x_2)$ is wrong, it should be close to $0.1357$. See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0.25%2C+1.2163%7D%2C%7B0.5%2C+1.357%7D%2C%7B1%2C+1.3817%7D) link for **an** interpolating polynomial. I think it is the lagrange polynomial, but I'm not sure. I can't help you with d), I don't remember about this.

Comment: I will correct that.Thank you very much.

Comment: another question: Does anyone know why should I use radians instead of degree?

Comment: I think there is a miscalculation in $l_0(x)$. I got it to be $l_0(x)=-8x^3+14x^2-7x+1$.

Comment: ... and in $l_1(x)$ there is a missing $x$. It should not have a constant term.

Comment: Thank you.THeres also a mistake in lo btw

Comment: @Kyle but why exactly radians?